# Flask - jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'employee' is undefined

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a page that displays `Employees Masterlist` and I wanted to do is when I clicked the `Employee No.` it will view the timesheet of that employee.

I tried using this as the result of my research.

In my `routes.py`

```
@app.route("/employee/<int:employee_id>")
def employee(employee_id):
  employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(employee_id)
  return render_template('emp_timesheet.html', employee=employee)
```

Here is my `masterlist.html`

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contract</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for employee in list_employee %}
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('employee', employee_id=employee.id) }}">{{ employee.employee_number }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ employee.last_name }}, {{ employee.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.contract }}</td>
            <td class="center">{{ employee.title }}</td>
            <td class="center">{{ employee.salary }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
File "/home/jxmtsi/Desktop/flask_training/rep/templates/header.html", line 293, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "/home/jxmtsi/Desktop/flask_training/rep/templates/masterlist.html", line 27, in block "content"
<td><a href="{{ url_for('employee', employee_id=employee.id) }}">{{ employee.employee_number }}</a></td>  
File "/home/jxmtsi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'employee' is undefined
```

Comment: The error is caused by `url_for()` that does not find your view function `employee()`. I would recommend not to use the same name for view functions and variables, it is rather error prone and can easily create conflicts. If I was you I would rename the function `employee()` to `getEmployeeById()` for example. If Jinja2 still does not find the function, I would look for the error in the app structure and eventually use flask's blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that a problem is in your Python code, more precisely in a communication between your application and SQL base. Or, maybe, you do not have in SQL database a data about requested employee_id.

Check, does variable `employee` in method `employee (employee_id)` is receiving data from your database. For example, try `print(employee.last_name)`:

```
@app.route("/employee/<int:employee_id>")
def employee(employee_id):
  employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(employee_id)
  print(employee.last_name) # or print other value from table (Model) Employee
  # print(employee.id)
  return render_template('emp_timesheet.html', employee=employee)
```